# Problemas com a nova versão do Meteor por causa do MongoDB

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, mongodb, meteorjs, meteor

Acabei de instalar a nova versão do meteor 1.4 e estou seguindo o tutorial do Alura. Ocorreu tudo OK na instalação e na inicialização do host:3000 e apareceu as informações do meteor. Porém assim que eu crio uma pasta chamada "models" e insiro um arquivo chamado "tarefas.js" para utilizar o MongoDB ele dá este erro e o server não roda mais. Inseri o mongoDB no patch das Variaveis de ambiente também não funcionou:

> Your app is crashing. Here's the latest log:
>
> C:\Users\thiag\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:280
>                         throw(ex);
>                         ^
>
> TypeError: Mongo.Collections is not a function
>       at meteorInstall.models.tarefas.js (models/tarefas.js:1:11)
>       at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:153:1)
>       at require (packages/modules-runtime/.npm/package/node_modules/install/install.js:82:1)
>       at C:\Users\thiag\Documents\gabarito\tasklist.meteor\local\build\programs\server\app\app.js:13:1
>       at C:\Users\thiag\Documents\gabarito\tasklist.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:292:10
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (C:\Users\thiag\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_2\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\underscore\underscore.js:79:11)
>       at C:\Users\thiag\Documents\gabarito\tasklist.meteor\local\build\programs\server\boot.js:128:5
>   Exited with code: 1 Your application is crashing. Waiting for file
>   change.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar Mongo.Collection, sem o 's' no final.

Caso você ainda não tenha resolvido, espero que te ajude!